# Cisco WLC - SSID configuration not written to APs

Tags: cisco, wifi

I am trying to solve a problem with a Cisco WLC (virtual) running 7.4.

This has a single AP joined, a 1602E, running the 7.4 LWAPP image.

There is an AP group configured, which this AP is a member of, and there is a basic WPA2-PSK WLAN defined, broadcast out of this AP group, and this is bound to the management interface, so no VLANs.  A

While the AP is successfully configured for things like SSH access, or login credentials (so config updating works), and can successfully detect other APs for rogue detection (so the radios are working), the SSID configuration is not written to the device.

Below is the excerpt of the AP configuration.  Note that the only reason for the AP group was to simplify the setup for the AP.  The default-group has three WLANs defined with EAP auth, so another AP group was created with a single AP and single basic WLAN.

Any ideas how I can troubleshoot why the configuration is not getting setup?

```
ip ssh version 2
lldp run
bridge irb
!
!
!
interface Dot11Radio0
 antenna gain 0
 stbc
 beamform ofdm
 mbssid
 power client local
 packet retries 64 drop-packet
 no cdp enable
!
interface Dot11Radio1
 antenna gain 0
 stbc
 beamform ofdm
 mbssid
 power client local
 packet retries 64 drop-packet
 no cdp enable
!
interface GigabitEthernet0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0.1
 encapsulation dot1Q 1 native
 bridge-group 1
 bridge-group 1 spanning-disabled
 no bridge-group 1 source-learning
!
interface BVI1
 ip address dhcp client-id BVI1
!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the AP not being setup is that the vWLC can ony support FlexConnect mode on APs, not local, as is supported on traditional WLC appliances.

Once the AP was switched to FlexConnect mode, the AP radio configuration was configuration was correctly setup.

However, the answer provided by scottm32768 is also correct, even in this case, the SSID configuration does not appear in the config.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an AP available that I can SSH into right now to check, but I don't think the SSID configuration is stored on a lightweight AP. It's all handled at the controller. Only enough configuration is on the AP to get it into the network and talking to the controller.

You might want to make sure that the radio is administratively enabled in the controller. They are off by default.